# In Spring can same page be rendered using JSP tiles and Velocity tiles

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, velocity, apache-tiles

One may wonder why do I need this but we have an application which currently uses spring + JSP tiles to render pages in which say there is a common left navigation across all pages with content.

But now business is demanding freedom to decouple the left navigation from rest of UI in the same page. Reason being, that they want to have faster iterations in the left navigation than the rest of the page. Dedicated designers may work on it.

So as such I thought of giving them Velocity template in the left navigation and rest of page still be displayed using jsp tiles.

I only came across this http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?10714-MVC-Using-JSP-Velocity-Tiles-in-Same-WebAp

but couldn't find anything to say, same page can be displayed using velocity and jsp tiles (together).

I am willing to discount using Velocity with tiles for which there is no standard integration provided in spring (Struts does provide one).

Answer (score 1):

A tile can use any supported templating mechanism--there's nothing that says all tiles must use the same rendering engine.

Comment: yes but can a single view resolver cater to a file which is mix of jsp and vm. I guess not.